# Testing Values For Multiple Conditions in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I am having some difficulty finding out what's wrong with my code. I am trying to create a console app in C#. The program is supposed to ask the user to to input 3 numbers. All of the number must be greater than 0. The first number should be even, the second should be whole, and the third should be odd. My syntax seems to be correct, however, when I run the program, it seems to ignore the if (userInput > 0) part. Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int userInput;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter an even number.");
            userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (userInput > 0 && !isEven(userInput))
                return;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a whole number.");
            userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (userInput > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter an odd number.");
            userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (userInput > 0 && isEven(userInput))
                return;
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations!");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch { }
    }

    static bool isEven(int value)
    {
        if (value % 2 == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }       
}
```

If anyone could tell me how to properly test both conditions I would be eternally greatful. Thanks.

Comment: remove the empty catch block.  It will only ever hide helpful information that you could use to figure out why a program is crashing.

Comment: Oh alright. Thank you for that information. I have revised my code by removing the empty catch block, but I am still encountering the same logic error. When I tested the program, I entered an even number for the first prompt. I also made that number -2, to test if the greater than 0 condition was being properly tested. It is still being ignored for whatever reason.

Comment: Having the empty catch was not the cause of your problem.  Removing it doesn't fix your code, it merely is good programming practice and will prevent other problems from being obscured from you.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for that explanation. I am currently in my first year studies majoring in computer programming, so I am certainly humble enough to say that I have much to learn.

Answer (score 3):

Your requirements for the first number entered are essentially:

> The number must be both positive and even.

The inverse of that is:

> If the number is not positive, **OR** it is not even, then it is not valid.

Your check says

> If the number is positive **AND** it is odd, then reject it

Meaning any number that is zero, negative, or even is valid.

What we have here is an application of DeMorgan's Law.  It states that:

```
!(A && B)
```

is equivalent to

```
!A || !B
```

So if a *valid* number is even **AND** positive, then an *invalid* number is not even **OR** not positive (not positive is less than or equal to zero).

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** you are checking for one Valid and other invalid scenario with Logical AND.

**Solution :** you need to use both invalid scenarios with Logical OR.

asper your requirement program should not proceed if any one of the following rule breaks:

**a.** userinput should be > 0
**b.** userinput should be odd,whole and even

**1.**  Replace This:

```
if (userInput > 0 && !isEven(userInput))
```

With This:

```
if (userInput <= 0 || !isEven(userInput))
```

**2.** Replace This:

```
if (userInput > 0 && isEven(userInput))
```

With This:

```
if (userInput <= 0 || isEven(userInput))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I see where I went wrong and I will use what you all have shown me for all future instances. This has been very helpful!

Comment: @user3311305: You are welcome :) glad tobe help of you.

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
if (userInput <= 0 || !isEven(userInput))
    return;
```

Since you want to quit when either the *number is not positive OR the number is not even*.

---

De Morgan's laws tell you how you can invert a logical expression. You do it by replacing each term by it's negated term and by replacing the AND's by OR's and vice versa.

So you could also write

```
if (userInput > 0 && isEven(userInput)) {
    // The user input is ok, continue
} else {
    return;
}
```

`userInput <= 0` is the negation of `userInput > 0`.

De Morgan's laws

```
NOT(A AND B) = NOT(A) OR NOT(B)
```

and

```
NOT(A OR B) = NOT(A) AND NOT(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way you've structured your program, there is likely supposed to be a return statement after the second if, IE:

```
if (userInput > 0)
    return;
```

However, this still does not address the problem that what you are probably trying to say is:

```
if (userInput <= 0)
    return;
```

Or somewhat more directly translated from English:

```
if (!(userInput > 0))
    return;
```

This change of sign applies to your other if statements as well, as others have mentioned.